# Microsoft Excel Grading System How To Exchange Integer for Percentage and Average

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a grading system that has a column with numbers that equate to percentages.

For example B2-B5 are each numbers depending on the grade. 1 equates to 85%, 2 equates to 95%, 3 equates to 97%, and 4 equates to 100%. In the top left at A1 I have a box for overall score that should take these numbers, interpret them as percentages, and then average them.

My goal was to use SUBSTITUTE and AVERAGE - I tried using Substitute but you seemingly can't apply this to a range of cells in a column at once and God I am annoyed.

Is this possible in Excel? I'm a Developer and could easily do this in literally anything else but it's a request for a co-worker and Excel is frustrating me to no end. I find it completely and utterly unintuitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [CHOOSE()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-choose-function).  In A1, put

```
=AVERAGE(CHOOSE(B2:B5,0.85,0.95,0.97,1))
```

This is an array formula, and must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If the formula is entered correctly, it will be surrounded by curly braces {} in the formula bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this made my day about 1000x better.

Comment: Wow, 1000 times? I should be so lucky. :-)  Seriously though, I'm glad to have helped.

Comment: I maintain that this is the simplest and easiest answer to my question, but I did end up utilizing VLOOKUP since, and I didn't specify this in my use case, but there's a possibility a value will be 0 or blank. If a value is 0 or blank CHOICE will throw a value error, and I wasn't sure if I could get around it.

Comment: `IFERROR()` will handle the case where a score is blank: `=AVERAGE(IFERROR(CHOOSE(B2:B5,0.85,0.95,0.97,1),""))`.  And an IF() statement can eliminate zero values if you don't want them to figure into an average.  I'm not sure what you'd want to do with zeroes.  If they really scored 0, I guess you'd want the average to include that score.  If 0 means they did not take the test, and had a good excuse, then probably the 0 shouldn't be included in the average.  In any case, it sounds like you have a solution that works for you.

Comment: BTW, I've never had this many votes for an answer before.  Thanks, everyone.  Glad you liked it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX({0.85,0.95,0.97,1},N(IF(1,$B$2:$B$5*1))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

It creates an array of the numbers in the range.  Then it passes that range to the INDEX.  So as it iterates the array it will change the numbers for the decimal percentage and pass all those to the AVERAGE:

[image]

Comment: Gaaah! The bizarre "de-referenced" INDEX() function.  It amazes me that you have to jump through these hoops to get this to work correctly.  Leave out N() or IF() or the *1 and it doesn't work.  Seems to me that INDEX() ought to be able to take a simple range or array for the row_num, and return an array.  But enough railing against the Excel gods, and +1 for your knowledge of the Hidden Excel Arcana. :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch I just learned this about 9 month ago, and if you look at the edits you can see my first pass did not work.  It is a pain.  And I agree it should.  But I also think we could use some things like Google Spread sheet's Filter and Query.

Comment: Hi @Scott, I just learned about it a few weeks ago. Tried to use it to get a discontinuous set of values from a 2D array, but couldn't get it to work right.  Needed to "de-ref" both row_num and col_num.  I think I'll go back and try the *1.

Comment: Hah! [I got it to work](https://superuser.com/questions/1296572/return-sum-of-multiple-vlookups?answertab=oldest#tab-top).  Thanks for the inspiration, @Scott.  I put the *1 in a formula I had tried before, and it worked.  But then I took it out, and it **still** worked.  Go figure.  So what the heck is the *1 doing in your formula?  Arcane is the right word.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate possibility - if you can use a few other cells for intermediate calculations (possibly in hidden columns, or even on another sheet):

- Use a reference table to store the relationship between scores and percentages
- Use a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to convert each score to a percentage
- Use [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/average-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6) to combine all the percentages

An advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require the scores to be sequential numbers ; it will work just as well with alphabetic or worded scores. There are no arcane tricks required, or array formulas involved.

Screenshot with formulas:
[image: Formulas: D2: =VLOOKUP(B2,$G$2:$H$5,2,FALSE) A1: =AVERAGE(D2:D5)]

Screenshot of output: 
[image: Output, numeric scores]

Screenshot with alphabetic scores:
[image: Output, alphabetic scores]

Comment: There's a [really old movie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tobor_the_Great_poster.jpg) with one of your relatives in it.