# complex excel double INDEX MATCH formula which returns and uses a unique value summary array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a first aid record in Excel and I'm trying to automate some calculations that are done each year.

I have attached a sample file (with no identifiers) to illustrate the issue.  A Dropbox [link is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtpptqxqsa5lamc/MedicHoursTrial.xlsx?dl=0).

I am trying to calculate total hours worked by each medic, per year, on Worksheet "Stats", using data from the other Sheets.

The cases seen by each medic are recorded on the Worksheet "Summary" in a Table named "Record". For each case, the year, shift, medic's name, and whether there are errors in the record are listed.

Each shift has a unique identifier listed on Worksheet "TimeIndex" in a Table named "ShiftValueT".

I am trying to write a formula which does the following:

1. Identifies rows matching multiple criteria (Year, Medic, ISERROR=FALSE())
2. Uses those rows to identify the UniqueShift values which correspond
3. Creates an array from unique values of the UniqueShift column which
   correspond (ie removes duplicates).
4. Uses those unique values (INDEX MATCH) in the ShiftValueT table to find the corresponding hours per UniqueShift type
5. Sums all the instances of hours corresponding to UniqueShifts identified

I've gotten this far (as an array formula):

`=SUM(INDEX(ShiftValueT[[Value]:[Value]],MATCH(INDEX(Record[[UniqueShift]:[UniqueShift]],MATCH(B$1&FALSE()&$A2,Record[[Year]:[Year]]&Record[[ISERROR]:[ISERROR]]&Record[[Medic]:[Medic]],0)),ShiftValueT[[UniqueShift]:[UniqueShift]],0)))`

but this only returns the first instance of UniqueShift and the single hours reference in the ShiftValueT.

How can I modify my formula to return the sum of all the hours?

Note: I would prefer not to use VBA.

Comment: How do you want to handle the Pre and Post shifts where no hours are listed in the Shift ValueT table?

Comment: Also, why would you want to "remove duplicates" in Step 3? If a Shift is in the array, it's because a combination of year, medic, and no error was found, and there could easily be many of those in a year. Presumably, you will want to sum the hours for all instances of a particular medic's cases during that shift in a year.

Comment: The record sheet contains a reference for the medic on per patient seen. so their 'being on shift' is displayed with every patient record. if you summed every instance of their shift being recorded, you would get many multiples of the actual hours worked. therefore duplicate entries need to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would recommend using a pivot table for this type of operation.
If a pivot table is not an option, a way to solve this would be to

1. Change the '-' for the PRE and POST to 0 on the 'ShiftValueT' Table.
2. Add a column to the 'Record' table called Time Index value and use a Vlookup to get the corresponding time value for each record.

`=VLOOKUP([@UniqueShift],ShiftValueT,2,FALSE)`

2. Then on the stats tab, you have 2 options depending on your Excel Year. For 2016, you can use a sumproduct Formula (This is in cell Stats!B2)

`=SUMPRODUCT((Record[Medic]=Stats!$A2)*(Record[Year]=Stats!B$1)*(Record[ISERROR]=FALSE)*Record[Time Index Value])`

or if you have previous versions of excel (to get {} press Ctrl + Shift + Enter when exiting the cell)

```
{=SUM(IF(Record[Medic]=Stats!$A2,IF(Record[Year]=Stats!B$1,IF(Record[ISERROR]=FALSE,Record[Time Index Value],0),0),0))}
```

Note: If this you do need to not include any duplicates, performing a remove duplicates on the 'Record' table data before using the formulas. Or follow the below Steps

1. Add another column to the 'Records' Table called "Duplicates" (This should be in column F) and insert this formula in F2. Note This make require Excel 2016

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A3,$A3,$B$2:$B3,$B3,$B$2:$B3,$B3,$C$2:$C3,$C3,$D$2:$D3,$D3,$E$2:$E3,$E3) >1, "Duplicate row", "")`

2. Update formulas to

`=SUMPRODUCT((Record[Medic]=Stats!$A2)*(Record[Year]=Stats!B$1)*(Record[ISERROR]=FALSE)*(Record[Duplicate]<>"Duplicate row")*Record[Time Index Value])`

or

`{=SUM(IF(Record[Medic]=Stats!$A2,IF(Record[Year]=Stats!B$1,IF(Record[ISERROR]=FALSE,IF(Record[Duplicate]<>"Duplicate row",Record[Time Index Value],0),0),0),0))}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a helper column, as suggested in the other answer, really simplifies the problem.  If you can do that, I recommend it.

The columns need to be locked in the formula though:

`=SUMPRODUCT((Record[[Medic]:[Medic]]=Stats!$G2)*(Record[[Year]:[Year]]=Stats!H$1)*(Record[[ISERROR]:[ISERROR]]=FALSE)*Record[[Hours]:[Hours]])`

I named the new column "Hours", as you can see.

If you can't add a helper column, then the solution requires the very strange [*de-referenced* INDEX() formula](https://superuser.com/questions/1296572/return-sum-of-multiple-vlookups/1296832#1296832), which you can read more about in the linked question.

`=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(ShiftValueT[Value],MATCH(INDEX(Record[UniqueShift],N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:A$350)/((Record[Year]=Stats!B$1)*(Record[Medic]=Stats!$A2)*(Record[ISERROR]=FALSE)),ROW(A$1:A$70))))),ShiftValueT[UniqueShift],0)),0))`

Strangely, the columns don't have to be locked in this formula.  Both of these formulas gave the same answers, shown in your completed table below:

[image]

Neither of these formulas remove duplicates.  Please comment if you need that.

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to respond. As stated in point 3 of my question, a solution needs to remove duplicates.

I love the de-referenced INDEX() formula, just in general though.

Comment: I have sort of a love/hate relationship with it.  I'll take a crack at removing duplicates tomorrow.